# Fetch API can't load '.php' local file - React JS + PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, fetch-api

I am working on a React JS application. Where I am using PHP and MySQL at the back end and React JS at the front end. What I am trying to do is to make a simple API 'fetch()' call to the back end and to get some data. My React App is running on "http://localhost:3000/". I have made a folder called "api/index.php" in the root directory of the React Application. When I try to make the call I get the error "File not found : 404". I don't know why.

**Fetch API in a component**

```js
fetch("/api/index.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => console.log(res))
```

**Files Structure**
[image]

> Please note that I am running the whole app in `wamp` server directory `www/react-app/`

Comment: Dont you think you need to give path like this in React Js /api/index.php

Comment: How did you start your React application?

Comment: @KoalaYeung using "create-react-app"

Comment: @Jaymin yes, I have mistyped the code, I made an update now.

Comment: can't you locally host the `php` code on the server

Comment: I could, but I got to use it in this way. What's the best alternative ? @IshanJoshi

Comment: How are you running your php/MySQL backend? Do you have another apache running on a different port and serve through that? If that is the case then your URL would be http://localhost:{apache-port}/api/index.php

Comment: @StavrosAngelis as I mentioned, I am having the 'api' folder in the root directory, not hosted elsewhere.

Comment: That is not going to work. You would need to create a separate web-server to serve your php project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot serve php with `create-react-app` development server (i.e. `npm run start`). As @EliasSoares pointed out, your PHP needs to be parsed on server side by `php-fpm` or Apache's `mod_php` setup.

Either you should:

- Build the create-react-app statically (i.e. `npm run build`). Then manually copy the build result, together with your `/api` PHP code, to the WAMP document root. This way works, but you will need to copy your JS / assets folder to WAMP every time your ReactJS code is updated.

  Or
- Serve PHP with WAMP on a different localhost port (say `locahost:8080`). Still develop your CRA application with development server (i.e. `npm run start`) at the same time. You need to modify your fetch URL like this:

  ```
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/index.php', options).then(...);
  ```

  This way, you need to correctly code your PHP to deal with [CORS preflight
  request and header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
  If you're using some popular PHP framework, I'm sure they'd have some middleware
  / plugin solution for this problem.

I think the 2nd option, although more troublesome to setup, is the more flexible solution for a better development experience.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad: Your `fetch` call didn't specified the hostname and port. In that case, your browser would presume the path to be on the same host:port (i.e. `http://localhost:3000`), which is the CRA development server that has no ability to parse and run the PHP code.

Comment: And if you just change the `fetch` URL to your WAMP port, you'd most probably encounter the CORS issue I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I will take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

Before all, your file is outside the `public` directory, so it's not accessible from your dev webserver. Also, looks like you are mixing concepts here. Keep some things in mind:

1. A react application is build from the your sourcecode and served using some dev webserver usually while developing.
2. PHP files need to be parsed on server side, usually as a extension to apache or nginx.
3. If you try to serve your file without a PHP parser, you will expose your source code to the world instead of having it executed.

Comment: I got your point, but what If I build React App, then also I will be supposed to host the `.php` code separately ?

Comment: Yes. It's the best practice, create a whole new application just for your api.

Comment: Updated my answer to a more comprehensive version.

Comment: My PHP code is already on the Wamp, I am serving the whole react app in WAMP.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run your localhost/.../api/index.php if you are using xampp or local server for PHP and SQL.
No local is included in your link.